# Regular expressions for two or more words php

Tags: php, regex

I have job titles like:

```
Reactive Customer Coach
Customer Reactive Coach
Technical Reactive Customer Coach
Field Engineer
Customer Engineer for FTTC
```

I would like to match:

`Reactive Coach` (Doesn't matter where `Reactive` keyword or `Coach` keyword occurs in the string)
Also would like to match `Engineer` keyword (again it can occur anywhere in the string)

It should return `FALSE` if these keywords are not found.

What would be a suitable regular expression for the above scenarios? (I am new to Regular expressions so haven't tried anything myself yet)

Comment: Can't get it, but perhaps, you are looking for [`^(?=.*\bReactive\b)(?=.*\bCoach\b).*$|^(?=.*\bEngineer\b).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/pA7zC2/2)? Or anything similar?

Comment: I want to make sure that Reactive|reactive|REACTIVE Coach|COACH|coach BOTH are present in the string. Would this do that?

Comment: The `i` ignore-case option will do that, yes. I just do not understand what exact outcome you need. Isn't anubhava's answer enough? Or you do not like the idea of using both `Reactive...Coach|Coach....reactive` in the regex? I am afraid you want to match non-continuous text, which is impossible with regex. If you just want to check if specific lines contain specific whole words, and get the lines, too, my regex is almost what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex in PHP:

```
(?|(\bReactive\b).*?(\bCoach\b(?! *OM\b))|(\bCoach\b).*?(\bReactive\b)|(\bEngineer\b))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pN8tY5/4)

`(?!...)` is a **non-capturing group**. Sub-patterns declared within each alternative of this construct will start over from the same index.

Comment: This has to match Reactive Coach or Coach Reactive. Would it do this?

Comment: I am trying to get my head around the RegEx Demo site. Struggling to make it case in-sensitive i.e. i want it to match reactive coach as well as Reactive Coach as well. Any idea where to put the `i` in the above regex?

Comment: It is working but there is a problem... it also matches the `Proactive Coach OM - Scotland` & `proactive Coach Operational Manager - Scotland`. There is a difference between a `reactive coach` and `reactive coach OM or operational manager. what to do?

Comment: Sorry for a delay response. I think I couldn't explain well. The thing is I wish to match `Reactive Coach` or `Reactive Customer Coach` But I do not wish to match `Reactive Coach OM`. Any idea how that could be achieved?

Comment: the guru of regex...just one last thing please... I wish to match `Operational Manager - Inverness & Naim
OM (CD) - Orkney asjdhaskjdh kahsd kjash 
OM BVG117
Operations Manager
Covering Operations Manager
Service Delivery Operational Manager` But I do not wish to match `Reactive Coach OM
reactive coach operational manager OR Reactive coach operations manager`. I created an example here...https://regex101.com/r/uA7gJ7/2 could you please check and let me know what the error was?

Comment: I am actually not able to understand the requirement from your demo link. Would it possible to create a separate question and clarify all the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

For simple matches regexp is not neccessary

```
<?php
/**
*/
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$in = [
 'Reactive Customer Coach'
,'Customer Reactive Coach'
,'Technical Reactive Customer Coach'
,'Field Engineer'
,'Customer Engineer for FTTC'
,'No such as'
];

function x($s) {
    if ( false !== mb_strpos($s,'Reactive') ) {
        return false !== mb_strpos($s,'Coach');
    }
    return false !== mb_strpos($s,'Engineer');
}

foreach ($in as $i) {
    echo $i,' ',x($i)?'Match':'',"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php), case-insensitive (Reactive|reactive|REACTIVE) [stripos](http://php.net/stripos)

```
if(stripos($mystring, 'reactive') != FALSE && stripos($mystring, 'coach') != FALSE){
    //string contains reactive or Coach
} else if(stripos($mystring, 'engineer') != FALSE){
    //string contains Engineer
} else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: matches Reactive and Coach independently, as I understand OP wants both

Comment: `and` not `or` to match both